# Can we screen record without any android app in Android version 4.1?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, android-versions, screencast

I search a lot on Play store but did not find any screen recorder app in play store which compatible on Android version 4.1

Comment: If you're rooted, there's [SCR Screen Recorder](http://www.scr-screen-recorder.com/). Otherwise, I've never heard native screen recording from the OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because in android 4.1 
there is no such facilities have been provided